# SVN compare two folders and export differences in Command Prompt

Tags: windows, shell, svn

How is possible to compare two folders in SVN and export the differences to another folder in **windows command prompt**?

With tortoise svn gui, we can compare two URLS select all and export selection files to a folder. As mentioned in [export changed files using tortoise svn to another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110961/export-changed-files-using-tortoise-svn-to-another-directory).

Is it possible to do it from command prompt ?!

I see list of commands at https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html but could not find any thing.

I find an script at https://www.electrictoolbox.com/subversion-export-changed-files-cli/ but it with was for the linux,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the [shell script for Linux](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/subversion-export-changed-files-cli/) you mentioned to work with Windows. The first variant (`svn-export.bat`) works with two different revisions in a repository. The second variant (`svn-localexport.bat`) will work with two local directories.

It uses the `svn diff --summarize -r revision-from:revision-to repository` as svn command to work. Create a batch file: `svn-export.bat` copy the following content into it and use it by:

```cmd
svn-export revision-from revision-to repository target-directory
```

**svn-export.bat:**

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set INVARGS=0
if [%1] == [] set INVARGS=1
if [%2] == [] set INVARGS=1
if [%3] == [] set INVARGS=1
if [%4] == [] set INVARGS=1
if %INVARGS% == 1 (
   echo Usage: %0 ^<revision_from^> ^<revision_to^> ^<repository^> ^<target_directory^>"
   goto eof
)

rem set up nice names for the incoming parameters to make the script more readable
set "revision_from=%1"
set "revision_to=%2"
set "repository=%3"
set "target_directory=%~4"

rem the findstr is needed so we only get added/modified files and not the deleted ones or anything else
set "svnCommand=svn diff --summarize -r%revision_from%:%revision_to% %repository% ^| findstr /B "[AM]""

if not exist "%target_directory%" ( mkdir "%target_directory%" )

rem go into target directory
pushd "%target_directory%"
for /f "delims=" %%L in ('%svnCommand%') do (
   rem convert line like: "A       http://..." to "http://..."
   set "filename=%%L"
   rem echo.before: ^<!filename!^>
   set "find=*%repository%/"
   call set filename=%%filename:!find!=%%
   rem echo.after:  ^<!filename!^>

   rem don't export if it's a directory we've already created
   if not exist "!filename!" (
      for %%F in ("!filename!") do set "directory=%%~dpF"
      if not exist "!directory!" ( mkdir "!directory!" )
      svn export -r %revision_to% %repository%/!filename! "%cd%\!filename!"
   )
)
popd

rem to summarize any deleted files or directories at the end of the script uncomment the following lines
rem echo.Deleted files:
rem svn diff --summarize -r%revision_from%:%revision_to% %repository% | findstr /B "[D]"

:eof
```

---

The next script is nearly the same but it compares two local directories that are managed by svn. Therefore it uses: `svn diff --summarize --old folder-old --new folder-new` as svn command. Use it via:

```cmd
svn-localexport folder-old folder-new target-directory
```

**svn_localexport.bat:**

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set INVARGS=0
if [%1] == [] set INVARGS=1
if [%2] == [] set INVARGS=1
if [%3] == [] set INVARGS=1
if %INVARGS% == 1 (
   echo Usage: %0 ^<folder_old^> ^<folder_new^> ^<target_directory^>"
   goto eof
)

rem set up nice names for the incoming parameters to make the script more readable
set "folder_old=%~1"
set "folder_new=%~2"
set "target_directory=%~3"

pushd "%folder_old%"
set "folder_old_abs=%cd%"
popd
pushd "%folder_new%"
set "folder_new_abs=%cd%"
popd

rem the findstr is needed so we only get added/modified files and not the deleted ones or anything else
set "svnCommand=svn diff --summarize --old "%folder_old_abs%" --new "%folder_new_abs%" ^| findstr /B "[AM]""

if not exist "%target_directory%" ( mkdir "%target_directory%" )

rem go into target directory
pushd "%target_directory%"
for /f "delims=" %%L in ('%svnCommand%') do (
   rem convert line like: "A       C:\Users\...\src.c" to "src.c"
   set "filename=%%L"
   rem echo.before: ^<!filename!^>
   set "find=*%folder_old_abs%\"
   call set filename=%%filename:!find!=%%
   rem echo.after:  ^<!filename!^>

   rem don't export if it's a directory we've already created
   if not exist "!filename!" (
      for %%F in ("!filename!") do set "directory=%%~dpF"
      if not exist "!directory!" ( mkdir "!directory!" )
      echo copy "%folder_new_abs%\!filename!" "%cd%\!filename!"
      copy "%folder_new_abs%\!filename!" "%cd%\!filename!"
   )
)
popd

rem to summarize any deleted files or directories at the end of the script uncomment the following lines
rem echo.Deleted files:
rem svn diff --summarize --old "%folder_old_abs%" --new "%folder_new_abs%" | findstr /B "[D]"

:eof
```

---

Note that both batch scripts doesn't overwrite target files if they are already exists. If you want to change that remove the corresponding if statement.

Comment: It exports the diff log but I am looking for folder structure which shows same as tortoise export

Comment: Now I got your question, sorry I misread your question and will change my answer.

Comment: I changed my answer, the script I attached works exactly the same as the script you have posted for Linux.

Comment: Thanks I test it with `svnexport 100 110 https://127.0.0.1/svn/My-Repo c:\test` and the result was a folder named `!directory!` in the `c:\test` folder !

Comment: Dear @AndreKampling the final edit worked! Thanks. By the way, this script compares two revisions, not two folders. I marked this as correct, Because this script is also very helpful!! But do you think it is possible to compare two folders and export the diffs.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it compares 2 revision as the script you've posted does that as well. I will change the script so that it will work with directories too. As an alternative there is WinMerge as posted on SO already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14138991/8051589.

Comment: It will be great, I am looking forward to script update !